# Moving the screen scroll position after page jumps to anchor point?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a menu on a single webpage whose links move the page to the section with the corresponding ID. However, there is a sticky header that is covering the top part of each section, so I want to scroll slightly to compensate.

I'm trying to determine a way to scroll the page by 50px *after* the page moves to a section. I tried doing a `.click()` event listener on each link, but it appears that the page is moved after the callback is issued, negating my attempt to scroll.

My code looks like the following:

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-1"><a href="#1">1</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-2"><a href="#2">2</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-3"><a href="#3">3</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4"><a href="#4">4</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS: (the two interior lines work in the console but not in the page code itself)

```
$('#menu-item-1 a').click(function(){
    var y = $(window).scrollTop(); 
    $(window).scrollTop(y-50);
});
```

Is there a way to listen for a link action to be completed, then run my scroll code?

Answer (score 0):

did you try setting a timeout, it will have a flicker effect though (unnoticeable)

also you can change your click event to handle all the a tags within li item like this

```
$('li > a').click(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){  
        var y = $(window).scrollTop(); 
        $(window).scrollTop(y-50); }, 1);
});
```

here is a sample fiddle for you https://jsfiddle.net/fxabnk4o/16/

Comment: I was thinking this, but wanted to see if there was a cleaner way to do this. I've had experiences setting timeouts where if some event happens at a different speed on a different browser/machine, the hardcoded time limit might not work.

Comment: setting the timer to 50 ms should work... I am pretty sure if this is just a positioning to a div tag within the page without any other functionality it will be much quicker than that

Answer (score 0):

As you observed:

> but it appears that the page is moved after the callback is issued, negating my attempt to scroll

This happens because your **events attached to anchor tag will be executed before the anchor tags default behaviour**.
You are using **id** so you can use it to scroll also via javascript.
Here is a sample which I have tried out:
http://plnkr.co/edit/FzHYaxMCeOMTvWurtNRe?p=preview

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li id="menu-item-1"><a href="#1" onClick = "handleClick(event, 1)">1</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-2"><a href="#2" onClick = "handleClick(event, 2)">2</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-3"><a href="#3" onClick = "handleClick(event, 3)">3</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-4"><a href="#4" onClick = "handleClick(event, 4)">4</a></li>
</ul>

function handleClick(e, scrollElemId){
  e.preventDefault();
  window.scrollTo(0,document.getElementById(scrollElemId).offsetTop+50);
}
```